# When joining to a very small/empty table why MySQL makes a full scan in spite of I'm using "LIMIT"?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

EDIT: I removed the `GROUP BY` clause from the example queries but the same problem shows "When I join table x to an empty/1 row table y MySQL makes a full table scan on table x in spite of I'm using limit"

---

Original Question: 
I was trying to learn how to optimize my SQL queries and I encountered a behavior that I can't understand. having a schema like this

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbc4a/2)

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,   
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB ;


CREATE TABLE `school` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,   
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB ;


CREATE TABLE `users` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
   `country_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `fk_country_idx` (`country_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_users_country` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB ;


CREATE TABLE `user_school_mm` (
   `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `school_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `school_id`),
   KEY `fk_user_school_mm_user_idx` (`user_id`),
   KEY `fk_user_school_mm_school_idx` (`school_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_user_school_mm_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `fk_user_school_mm_school` FOREIGN KEY (`school_id`) REFERENCES `school` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

INSERT INTO country (name) VALUES ('fooCountry1');
INSERT INTO school (name) VALUES ('fooSchool1'),('fooSchool2'),('fooSchool3');
INSERT INTO users (name, country_id) VALUES
('fooUser1',1),
('fooUser2',1),
('fooUser3',1),
('fooUser4',1),
('fooUser5',1),
('fooUser6',1),
('fooUser7',1),
('fooUser8',1),
('fooUser9',1),
('fooUser10',1)
;
INSERT INTO user_school_mm (user_id, school_id) VALUES
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),
(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),
(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),
(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),
(5,1),(5,2),(5,3),
(6,1),(6,2),(6,3),
(7,1),(7,2),(7,3),
(8,1),(8,2),(8,3),
(9,1),(9,2),(9,3),
(10,1),(10,2),(10,3)
;
```

**QUERY 1 (Fast)**

```
-- GOOD QUERY (MySQL uses the limit and skip users table scan after 2 rows )
SELECT * 
FROM 
    users LEFT JOIN
    user_school_mm on users.id = user_school_mm.user_id
ORDER BY users.id ASC
LIMIT 2
-- takes about 100 milliseconds if users table is 3 million records
```

Explain

```
+---+-----------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------+----------+---------+---------------+------+-----------+
|id |select_type|table          | type | possible_keys                     | key      | key_len | ref           | rows | Extra     |
+---+-----------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------+----------+---------+---------------+------+-----------+
|1  |SIMPLE     |users          |index |PRIMARY,fk_country_idx             | PRIMARY  |4        |               |2     |           |
|1  |SIMPLE     |user_school_mm |ref   |PRIMARY,fk_user_school_mm_user_idx | PRIMARY  |4        |tests.users.id |1     |Using index|
+---+-----------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------+----------+---------+---------------+------+-----------+
```

**QUERY 2 (Slow)**

```
-- BAD QUERY (MySQL ignores the limit and scanned the entire users table )
SELECT * 
FROM 
    users LEFT JOIN
    country on users.country_id = country.id
ORDER BY users.id ASC
LIMIT 2
-- takes about 9 seconds if users table is 3 million records
```

Explain

```
+---+-----------+--------+------+------------------------+-----+---------+-----+------+---------------------------------------------------+
|id |select_type|table   | type | possible_keys          | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra                                             |
+---+-----------+--------+------+------------------------+-----+---------+-----+------+---------------------------------------------------+
|1  |SIMPLE     |users   |ALL   | PRIMARY,fk_country_idx |     |         |     | 10   | Using temporary; Using filesort                   |
|1  |SIMPLE     |country |ALL   | PRIMARY                |     |         |     | 1    | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)|
+---+-----------+--------+------+------------------------+-----+---------+-----+------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

I don't understand what is going on behind the scenes, I thought If I used the primary key of the users table for the ordering and grouping, MySQL will take the first 2 rows of the users table and continue the joining, but it seems it didn't do that and scanned the entire table in query 2

**Why MySQL scanned the entire table in query2 while it takes only the first 2 rows in query1 ?**

*MySQL version is 5.6.38*

Comment: I'm guessing it ends the scan once enough rows are found.

Comment: @shawnt00 but in query 2 it scanned the entire table (10 rows in this sample) and 3 million rows if users table is 3 million rows

Comment: Your "good" query is also bad... `SELECT * .... GROUP BY users.id` is bad ansi GROUP BY SQL.  It can result in bad unrelated data https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: Don't take rows in explain output to literally, the row column is a estimate for the InnoDB engine.

Comment: @RaymondNijland with 3 million rows the rows output is about (**2400000**) with query 2 and (**2**) with query 1

Comment: the limit is applied to the result  .. and is the db engine that choice how and when  the limit is reached .. anuway you are using sql in improper manner .. you should not use group by without aggregation function and for unuseful result  .. if you need distinct result you should use select distinct and not an improper group by .. and is the improper use of group by that force the db engine to scan  the entire tables.

Comment: @scaisEdge in my real query I used `group by` with `group_concat()` . But In the question I just want to reproduce the problem with the minimal code and show that changing only the joined-to table (`country`, `user_school_mm` ) result in 2 different execution plans. And regarding *"and is the improper use of group by that force the db engine to scan the entire tables"* I removed the group by clause from the 2 queries and nothing changes, query 1 takes only 2 rows , and query 2 scanned the entire table.

Comment: @scaisEdge *"and is the db engine that choice how and when the limit is reached"* and that is why I asked the question. I want to know why the engine did that in this example

Comment: These are malformed queries, using `select *` with `group by`.  Perhaps that explains why MySQL doesn't attempt to optimize them.  These are easily replaced by more appropriate logic that will result in the correct execution plan.

Comment: @shawnt00 thank you for your time and comment, If you are interested in the issue, please see the accepted answer.

Comment: @scaisEdge thank you for your time and comment, If you are interested in the issue, please see the accepted answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you very much Mr Gordon and sorry for bothering you again. It turns out this is an expected behavior from the optimizer, please see the accepted answer.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. I actually only skimmed the first time and missed an important detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MySQL optimizer will decide on join order/method first, and then check whether, for the chosen join order, it is possible to avoid sorting by using an index.  For the slow query in this question, the optimizer has decided to use Block-Nested-Loop (BNL) join.

BNL is usually quicker than using an index when one of the tables is very small (and there is no LIMIT).

However, with BNL, rows will not necessarily  come in the order given by the first table. Hence, the result of the join needs to be sorted before applying the LIMIT.

You can turn off BNL by `set optimizer_switch = 'block_nested_loop=off';`

Comment: You.....Are.....A KING. I will read every word you say from now on. Thank you very much for the answer and thank you for MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is the misuse of `GROUP BY`.  Let's take the first query.  Even though it is "fast", it is still "wrong":

```
SELECT * 
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN user_school_mm on users.id = user_school_mm.user_id
    GROUP BY users.id
    ORDER BY users.id ASC
    LIMIT 2
```

A user can go to two schools.  The use of the many:many mapping `user_school_mm` claims that is a possibility.  So, after doing the `JOIN`, you get 2 rows for a single user.  But then, you `GROUP BY users.id`, to boil it down to a single row.  But... Which of the two school_id values should you use??

I am not going to try to address the performance issues until you present queries that make sense.  At that point it will be easier to point out why one query performs better than another.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest, I removed the `GROUP BY`  and MySQL still makes the same behavior. "If I joined the table to an empty table, MySQL makes a full scan to the first table". I provided a detailed steps in the answer to how to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

After some tests it turns out that if the second table(`user_school_mm`) has some data MySQL will not make full table scan on the first table, and if the second table(`country`) has no data/very little data (1 or 2 records) MySQL will do a full table scan. Why this happens? I don't know.

How to reproduce

1- Create a schema like this

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
   `ev_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `ev_note` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ev_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `table1` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,   
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,   
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

2- insert in the main table (`event` in this case) some data (I filled it with 35601000 rows)

3- leave table1 empty and insert 15 rows in table2

```
insert into table2 (name) values 
('fooBar'),('fooBar'),('fooBar'),('fooBar'),('fooBar'),
('fooBar'),('fooBar'),('fooBar'),('fooBar'),('fooBar'),
('fooBar'),('fooBar'),('fooBar'),('fooBar'),('fooBar');
```

4- now join the main table with table2 and retest the same query with table1

**Query 1 (Fast)**

```
select * 
from 
    event left join 
    table2 on event.ev_id = table2.id
order by event.ev_id
limit 2;
-- executed in 300 milliseconds measured by the client
```

Explain

```
+---+-----------+--------+------+----------------+--------+---------+------------------+------+--------+
|id |select_type|table   | type | possible_keys  | key    | key_len | ref              | rows | Extra  |
+---+-----------+--------+------+----------------+--------+---------+------------------+------+--------+
|1  |SIMPLE     |event   |index |                |PRIMARY |4        |                  | 2    |        |
|1  |SIMPLE     |table2  |eq_ref|PRIMARY         |PRIMARY |4        |tests.event.ev_id | 1    |        |
+---+-----------+--------+------+----------------+--------+---------+------------------+------+--------+
```

**Query 2 (Slow)**

```
select * 
from 
    event left join 
    table1 on event.ev_id = table1.id
order by event.ev_id
limit 2;
-- executed in 79 seconds measured by the client
```

Explain

```
+---+-----------+--------+------+----------------+--------+---------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+
|id |select_type|table   | type | possible_keys  | key    | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra                                             |
+---+-----------+--------+------+----------------+--------+---------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+
|1  |SIMPLE     |event   |ALL   |                |        |         |       |33506704 | Using temporary; Using filesort                   |
|1  |SIMPLE     |table1  |ALL   |PRIMARY         |        |         |       |1        | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)|
+---+-----------+--------+------+----------------+--------+---------+-------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

*MySQL version is 5.6.38*