# Format the date and time in MySQL default format

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, datetime-format

I have a MySQL table with forex tick data

```
pair     tick_date_time         price_low  price_high  
-------  ---------------------  ---------  ------------
USD/JPY  20091201 00:00:00.628  86.280000  86.286000   
USD/JPY  20091201 00:00:00.722  86.280000  86.289000   
USD/JPY  20091201 00:00:00.741  86.281000  86.289000   
USD/JPY  20091201 00:00:01.130  86.283000  86.289000   
USD/JPY  20091201 00:00:01.131  86.283000  86.289000
```

The date/time in this table is not formatted in MySQL default format. I use the query to format the data

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.tick_date_time, "%Y%m%d %H:%i:%s") FROM table AS t
```

This returns `NULL`. Any idea where I'm wrong? I also like to extract milliseconds if possible.

Comment: It helps when you include information about the data type of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the function `str_to_date()`, not `date_format()`:

```
SELECT str_to_date(t.tick_date_time, '%Y%m%d %H:%i:%s')
```

`date_format()` takes a date and produces a string.  `str_to_date()` takes a string and converts it to a date.

Comment: If you have time, can you please give [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339119/when-joining-to-a-very-small-empty-table-why-mysql-makes-a-full-scan-in-spite-of) a look