# Optimizing MySQL database for select statements when there are 1M records: store old data separately?

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I have a website where users maintain conversations with each other. Each comment is stored in a MySQL database. DB has a table named comment with a foreign key that refers to conversation. 
Messages of a conversation are returned to client by steps, limiting rows with a **"limit" clause** (this is important for my question). For instance,

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `user_to_id` = 1 and `conversation_id` = 4 limit 10,5
```

My question is next: if there were too many records in comments table, selects queries like above would be slower?
If it is, is a good practice store old records in a separate table or in a server file in order to speed up select queries only with recent comments?

Comment: If you properly index your database, and load data in smaller batches (i.e. you don't load last 10.000 comments at once), it should be fine. SQL is designed for handling huge datasets.

Comment: like @Qirel said SQL servers nowadays are designed to handle millions or billions off records just fine when indexed.. Meaning it can most likely handle table sizes of a couple of GB's or TB's sizes just fine.. For better scaling you can use partitions to improve that even more.

Comment: Thank you both. So, there is no need to store separately

Comment: *"So, there is no need to store separately"* @Angel partitions will do that automatic in MySQL it will make smaller table files..

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will read about partitions

Comment: [preoptimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) don't waste your time and change your code on an optimization that you **think** it will help, do populate your database with *DATA* and test every query you have.

Comment: Indexes beats data. Meaning even an average computer can handle millions or records *IF* the optimizer used the correct index.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and an `ORDER BY` clause.  _Then_ we can provide the optimal composite index to keep the speed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the query `` SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `user_to_id` = 1 and `conversation_id` = 4 limit 10,5 `` already returns the *most recent* messages, then your `limit` clause ensures speediness, there should be no issue with keeping millions of messages as you are limiting the resulting dataset.

Comment: Thank you. If there were no oposite comment from another user, later I will accept this answer

Comment: infact LIMIT should be used in combination with ORDER BY otherwise the results are non deterministic(random) @Angel

Comment: *"there should be no issue with keeping millions of messages as you are limiting the resulting dataset"* Also thats not true  `LIMIT 1000000, 1000` is slow because the server needs to store and fetch `1001000` records to throw away `1000000` again to keep the `1000`.. it's not that optimal  to use on large tables.

Comment: @RaymondNijland read my answer: *if [...] already returns the most recent messages*, I was implying Angel must have typed it as an example and didn't add the ORDER BY, otherwise he would be running a system with randomly ordered messages

Comment: @RaymondNijland you're right about how large limits make slow queries ( `LIMIT 1000000, 1000` ), but Angel only asked about `limit 10,5`, does having a large table affect the query significantly? (I'm genuinely curious).

Comment: [`Limit` doesn't always ensure performance.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339119/when-joining-to-a-very-small-empty-table-why-mysql-makes-a-full-scan-in-spite-of)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Accountantم